# Converting String to Ordered list in Java

Tags: java, arrays, tostring

I'm new to java and I was wondering how to convert an array output - like [x,y,z] - to an ordered list in parentheses - as in (x,y,z). I know how to do this in Python, so I'm assuming the code would be rather similar. I know that in order to make the array into a string, I just need to include the toString method in the print statement. However, what else should I do? There may be an obvious answer to this question that I'm overlooking...

EDIT: And also, How do you index an array if it's an array of arrays (or a 2D array, as some people call it). I would like to make an output that yields an ordered list and numbers which array it is as well.

Comment: What is "an ordered list in parentheses"? I don't know what that is (in a java context)

Comment: seems like this should be simple using String.replace(...)

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Your question says that you want to convert a string to an ordered list. But then you talk about converting an array into an ordered list. Do you mean that you want to insert the characters of a String into a list?

Comment: Maybe you should post the python code doing what you want as a clarification

Comment: Are you talking about parsing a string into an array of elements based on some delimiter?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
String myArray[] = { "y", "x", "z" };
List<String> myArrayList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(myArray));
Collections.sort(myArrayList);
System.out.println("myArrayList = " + myArrayList);
```

### output

```
myArrayList = [x, y, z]
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you mean structures not pure strings:

```
String[] strings = {"a", "b", "c"};
List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList(strings);
```

Regarding 2d arrays java has no support of 2d arrays. But you can create array of arrays and iterate over it using indexes:

```
    String[][] strings = {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"c", "d", "e"}, {"f", "g", "h"}};
    for (String[] arr : strings) {
        for (String str : arr) {

        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
        String[] arr = strings[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
            String str = arr[j];

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
    String s="[x,d,z]";
    String[] strings = s.replace("]", "").replace("[", "").split(",");
    List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList(strings);
    System.out.println(stringList);
    Collections.sort(stringList);
    System.out.println(stringList);
```

output 
    [x, d, z]
    [d, x, z]